# Calcular media de registros

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando calcular la media de los registros de una tabla en base al mes en que fueron creados.

Con este código agrupo los registros por meses en función de la columna "created_at"

```
$monthlyCounts = Viaje::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)as month'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(1) as count')
        )->groupBy('month')->get()->toArray()
```

.
Hasta aquí bien, obtengo un array con el numero de mes y el numero de registro creados en ese mes.

Este código devuelve todos los registros creados en el mes 0,1,2.... , pero necesitaría saber cuantos meses 0,1,2 ... ha encontrado para poder obtener la media de cada uno.

Comment: El último párrafo de tu pregunta no es claro, puedes explicarlo mejor?

Comment: @BetaM he explicado un  poco mejor lo que necesito obtener

Answer (score 0):

no se si entendí bien lo que quieres pero te dejo una consulta que suma las visitas por mes y saca el promedio de esas visitas por mes, ojala te sirva:

```
SELECT created_at as Mes, AVG(visita) as 'Promedio', SUM(visita) as Visitas FROM `viajes` GROUP BY Mes
```

[image: Resultado de consulta]

Editando mi respuesta para Laravel sería:

```
Use DB; //ponerlo después del namespace

$monthlyCounts = DB::select("SELECT created_at as Mes, AVG(visita) as 'Promedio', SUM(visita) as Visitas FROM `viajes` GROUP BY Mes");
```

Comment: Considera que el OP busca esto pero en Laravel entonces la consulta debería estar hecha con el query builder o con Eloquent, sin contar que ayudaría mucho no solo le dejes la consulta sino que además se la explicarás, checa [answer]